# Docker: provide custom context in python-sdk

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to emulate the following CLI command using the docker python-sdk:

```
docker build -t mytag -f path_to_my_dockerfile/Dockerfile ../../../.
```

So in this case I want it to build the Dockerfile using the build context `../../../.`.
I tried using the python-sdk for docker but it seems each time the build context is not the right one, I tried various combinations like :

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
clients.images.build(path="../../../.", fileobj="path_to_my_dockerfile/Dockerfile", tag="mytag")
```

but nothing seems to work. Looking into [the docker-py repo](https://github.com/docker/docker-py/blob/master/docker/api/build.py) is not helping.

Comment: just `cd ../../../` up there and then you can `docker build <whatever> . `, and you get the correct context

Comment: The problem is the python script calling docker is located at a fixed place and to cd inside the script would be very ugly.  What I could do is move the Dockerfile but it is not very convenient either and I figured this should not be too hard but I cannot make it work...

Comment: what exactly do you need up on `../../../`? can you show that dockerfile?

Comment: I am just using an ADD . to copy all the hierarchy of a git repo that is why I need the context to be the root folder of git.

Comment: so why dont you put the dockerfile there as well? dockerfile is supposed to be at your root dir

Comment: As I said in my comment I’d rather not. Is it really that difficult to port a simple CLI command into the python API ? Is it a known limitation of the sdk ?

Comment: FYI: the above code will throw error while taking in `fileobj ` as string. You'll need to provide it as byte Object `BytesIO(dockerfile.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: and of course you'll need `custom_context=True` if you provide fileobj. Looking at the docs, I realized that you don't necessarily have to provide both args together `path` and `fileobj`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to provide the `dockerfile` argument:

```
clients.images.build(
    path="../../../.",
    dockerfile="path_to_my_dockerfile/Dockerfile",
    tag="mytag"
)
```

Note that the `dockerfile` should be relative to `path`, not your current working directory.

If you have dockerfile and context relative to your current working directory, you may be able to compute the relative path with something like this:

```
dockerfile = pathlib.Path(os.path.normpath(dockerfile)).absolute()
context = pathlib.Path(os.path.normpath(context)).absolute()

path = dockerfile.relative_to(context)
```

Alternatively, you can also provide a custom build context, by creating a tarfile yourself with `custom_context`. This is the most flexible way, as you don't even need a filesystem that way.