# Docker python client NOT building image from custom context

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, sdk, dockerfile

**In short:** The problem is, I want docker client to run docker build command from user defined context.

**In Long:** 
So here is my directory structure;

```
main_directory
└── package
       ├──directory_x
       └──directory_y
          ├──docker
          |  └──Dockerfile 
          +-─dockerclient.py
          :
```

My docker file has a step where I need copy the entire `main_directory` into a `temp` folder.

```
COPY . /path/temp/main_directory/
```

from `main_directory` the following command works;

```
docker build -t foo:bar -f package/directory_y/docker/Dockerfile .
```

But I am not able to do this while using python docker client because it asks me to provide the `path` of Dockerfile and then it runs the `docker build` command from that given path. My `dockerclient.py` has following code;

```
import docker
from ast import literal_eval

class DockerBuildException(BaseException): pass

client = docker.from_env()
dirPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
# dirPath = path/to/main_directory/jagex_airflow/test

try:
    responce = client.images.build(path=dirPath + "/docker", tag="foo:bar")
    print(responce)
    for i in responce:
        if b'errorDetail' in i:
            d = literal_eval(i.decode('ascii'))
            raise DockerBuildException(d['errorDetail']['message'])
except DockerBuildException as e:
     print("Error: " + e.args[0])
     raise
```

The problem with this approach is `COPY .` will copy all the files/dirs from `~/main_directory/jagex_airflow/test/docker` into the container. Whereas i want this to copy all content from `main_directory`.

I also tried passing in Dockerfile path and context path separately

```
with open(dirPath + "/docker/Dockerfile") as file_:
    dockerfile = file_.read()
f = BytesIO(dockerfile.encode('utf-8'))

client.images.build(path="path/to/main_directory/", fileobj=f, tag="foo:bar")
```

But that didn't worked either.

I was wondering if is there any optional parameter to `client.images.build` to specify from where to run the `docker build` command, and a separate argument mentioning the path to `Dockerfile` ? 
A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023191/docker-provide-custom-context-in-python-sdk), but with no right answer. From the user comments, someone suggested to keep the Dockerfile in root directory, but that's not what I want to do. I mean, if it's possible to do from bare-bone `docker build` command, then why not by python client ? or is it true that docker python SDK has this limitation ? If that's the case, can someone recommend me any alternative python client for docker (if any) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `dockerfile` parameter instead

```
...    
responce = client.images.build(dockerfile=dirPath + "/docker/Dockerfile", tag="foo:bar")
...
```

https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/images.html

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a few issues here.

1. Building an image using a dockerfile that isn't in the docker's temp dir.
2. Copying the main project so that the container has access to it

### Let's address your first issue of building the dockerfile outside the tempdir:

```
with open(os.path.join(path_to_dockerfile, 'Dockerfile'), 'rb') as DockerFile:
    image, _ = client.images.build(fileobj=DockerFile, 
                                   labels={'name': 'some_name'})
    image.tag(repository='some_repository_name')
```

This lets you open a Dockerfile which is located pretty much anywhere (you can even do fancy footwork to access remote dockerfiles this way), and create an image from that file

### Copying the main project so it can be accessed from a container

Currently you're trying to do this from the image. This makes some sense, since it reduces code overhead, but isn't practical based on the python SDK, especially since docker is confined to the context of the docker-build tmp directory. There is a much more efficient and graceful solution on the container-side however:

```
container = client.containers.run(image='some_image', cmd='some_cmd(/bin/bash)'
                                  name='some_name',
                                  volumes={main_directory: {'bind': container_dir,
                                                            'mode': 'rw'}})
```

By mounting the filesystem to the container, you don't have to waste time copying the directory every time you build from the image, and you are freed from the pain of outsmarting docker's build context.

Note: Docker does NOT play nicely with symlinks. You may need to create a copy of the file-system (I recommend using shutil) which has symlinks resolved.